# Consume and replace elements in a vector with 1 or more elements

Tags: rust

I'm trying to figure out an efficient Rust way of consuming elements of a vector and replacing them with one or more elements (of the same type) like in the non-compiling example:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut myvec = vec![0, 1];
    println!("{:?}", myvec);
    
    for val in myvec.drain(..) {
        myvec.push(val+2);
        myvec.push(val+4);
    }
    println!("{:?}", myvec);
}
```

However, I am not even sure if Rust would even allow that as each operation needs a mutable reference (i.e. we need 2 mutable refs) but Rust can only allow one. Is there a way doing what I want to do or do I just need to have 2 separate vectors:

```rust
let mut myvec = vec![0, 1];
let mut newvec = Vec::new();
println!("{:?}", myvec);
    
for val in myvec.drain(..) {
    newvec.push(val+2);
    newvec.push(val+4);
}
println!("{:?}", newvec);
```

which outputs:

```
[0, 1]
[2, 4, 3, 5]
```

PS. I know that the [splice method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.splice) can achieve what I need but I also need a mutable reference inside the for loop.

Comment: Given that you are making the vec larger, it will likely need reallocating, and probably creating a new Vec isn't going to be much worse, performance-wise

Comment: Yeah I don't think there's any easy way to perform an "in-place flatmap either". You could always `remove()` entries from one end and add them to the other but the vec would then need to move all the items around which wouldn't be very fast (vecdeque would be more efficient then). In fact you would have the same issue here: the first item would replace the one being drained but the second item would have to "bump" all the items remaining in the vector.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are changing the size of the `Vec`, it's likely that it will need reallocation anyway. Additionally, you cannot mutate a `Vec` while you are iterating it (precisely because mutating it could cause it to reallocate). It won't be much different to collect into a new `Vec`:

```
myvec = myvec
    .drain(..)
    .flat_map(|val| iter::once(val + 2).chain(iter::once(val + 4)))
    .collect();
```

The chained iterator might not be as optimal as it could be. [In nightly Rust](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/65819), you could do:

```
#![feature(array_value_iter)]

use std::array;

myvec = myvec
    .drain(..)
    .flat_map(|val| array::IntoIter::new([val + 2, val + 4]))
    .collect();
```

Which should be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could swap elements of the same type directly in memory:

```
use core::mem::swap;

fn main() {
    let mut myvec = vec![0, 1];
    let mut result = Vec::new();
    println!("{:?}", myvec);

    for i in (0..myvec.len()).step_by(2) {
        let mut x = myvec[i] + 2;
        swap(&mut myvec[i], &mut x);
        result.push(x);

        if i + 1 < myvec.len() {
            let mut y = myvec[i + 1] + 4;
            swap(&mut myvec[i + 1], &mut y);
            result.push(y);
        }
    }

    println!("{:?} {:?}", myvec, result);
}
```

After posting I realized that you require replacing an element with more than one element, and this code won't do that.  I'll leave it up in case it helps, though.